# _preprocess_views_view not getting called

Tags: views, theming

Drupal 7, Views, Bootstrap theme sub theme in use

I have a views-view-table.tpl.php file in my sub theme and I am trying to preprocess some of the variables sent to this tpl. I created a function bootstrap_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) in my template.php and it is not getting called when I visit one of my views pages. Why would this be? Other preprocess functions are getting called from the same template file. I have tried flushing the cache.

```
function bootstrap_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  dsm($vars);
  dsm("aaaa");
  die;
}
```

Comment: First of all: Flush the cache.

Comment: I have tried flushing the cache. That did not work.

Comment: I am having a similar problem. mytheme_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) is not working, dpm($vars) also do not work in there. There is no $rows output in tpl file, Although tpl file is being rendered fine with html code. Cache flush also didn't work. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Then, we have to consider the following possibilities:

- The name of the function is bad typed. The structure for this case should be `template_preprocess_HOOK(&$variables)`. The second part (**_preprocces**) and third part (**_views_view**) is well typed, but are you sure the first part is well typed? I assume that "bootstrap" is the name of your theme.
- This template hasn't been called when you visit the page, for example, if the pages have been stored in cache_page table for anonymous users. Another possibility could be that a different template has been called.